# Get an image from a random entry

Tags: entries, image, forloop, random

I have a section with an text field and an image field. the asset field may sometimes be left blank. in this case, in my template, i want to grab the image from another random entry.

This is the code I'm trying to use, but when the image field is blank in my initial entry, I'm getting an error that Variable "image" doesn't exist.
Am I calling the random image incorrectly?

```
{% for stat in craft.entries.section('statistics').limit(1).order('RAND()') %}
{% if stat.image|length %}
    {% set image = stat.image.first() %}
{% else %}  
    {% for random in craft.entries.section('statistics').limit(1).image(':notempty:').order('RAND()') %}
        {% set image = random.image.first() %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}

{{ image.url('medium') }}')

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you can't only get stats with images? Something like
`{% set stat = craft.entries.section('statistics'.limit(1).order('RAND()')).image(':notempty') %}`

Comment: That would be ideal, but there are way more stats than images, so in this case it's not realistic for the client to require an image for every stat.

Answer (score 2):

I think something like this should work

```
{# First get all the stats #}
{% set stats = craft.entries.section('statistics') %}

{# iterate over those stat in a random order %}
{% for stat in stats.order('RAND()') %}

    {% if stat.image | length %}

        {% set image = stat.image.first %}

    {% else %}

        {# If there's no image, query for a random stat, excluding those without images #}
        {% set randomStat = stats.image(':notempty:').limit(1).order('RAND()') %}
        {% set image = randomStat.first.image.first %}

    {% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Seems like that should work, but I get this error: Impossible to invoke a method ("first") on a string variable (":notempty:").

Comment: Can you `dump` `randomStat.image` to see what's being returned there? It seems like it's not returning an asset model for some reason.

Comment: When i `dump` `randomStat.image`, I get this: `string(10) ":notempty:" string(10) ":notempty:" string(10) ":notempty:" string(10) ":notempty:" string(10) ":notempty:" string(10) ":notempty:"`

Comment: Interesting, I'm not totally sure what's happening here. Just to confirm, what version of Craft are you using?

Comment: I'm using  2.6.2981